# enum encoded value is nil while storing the class object in UserDefaults. Codable Protocol is already inherited

Tags: swift, codable

I am new to iOS and trying to store User object in UserDefaults. So that when the app is launched again, I can check user type and based on it, I need to navigate to relevant screen.

For that, I have created a User class as below (Codable) and it has one userType enum property!

```
enum UserType: Int, Codable {
    case userType1 = 0 
    case userType2 = 1
    case notDetermined = 2
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let label = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(Int.self)
        self = UserType(rawValue: label) ?? .notDetermined
    }
}

class User: Codable {
    public var userFullName: String? = ""
    public var userType: UserType? //= .notDetermined
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userFullName
    }
}
```

In my view Controller class, I am creating a new instance for User object and trying to store in user defaults as below:

```
        let newUser = User()
        newUser.userFullName = "Test"
        newUser.userType = userTypeBtn.isSelected ? .userType1 : .userType2
```

when I print the newUser's userType, I can see proper value whichever is selected. But after that, when I am trying to store it in userDefaults as below, it returns nil for userType property.

```
            do {
                let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: UserDefaultKey.currentUser)
                UserDefaults.standard.sync()
            } catch {
                print("Unable to Encode User Object: (\(error))")
            }
```

when I tried to print this **encoded** variable, and decoded it in console

```
JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: encoded).userType
```

it prints nil.

Please help me how can I store optional enum property in UserDefaults and retrieve it when needed using Codable

Comment: Why did you only include `userFullName` in the `CodingKeys` enum?

Comment: @Sweeper Because I am not getting it from Server and userType is an external property outside the JSON response !

Earlier I added userType as well in CodingKeys, but still the issue persisted !

Comment: Adding it shouldn't break your JSON parsing code though, does it? The reason why saving to `UserDefaults` doesn't work is because you are not including `userType` as a coding key.

Comment: "but still the issue persisted!" <-- did you encode the user again, or did you just tried to decode the old user that's already stored in user defaults? You should encode the user again. After that it should work.

Comment: @Sweeper I deleted the app from Simulator and relaunched it. My thinking about CodingKey was if we wish to define our own property name instead of what is received from Server, we can map server key with our own defined key. That's what I believed!

Comment: @Sweeper added userType in Coding key and it seems to be working fine now. Thank you for this great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include `userType` in your `CodingKeys` enum:

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case userFullName
    case userType
}
```

Or just delete the `CodingKeys` enum entirely, since by default, all the properties are included as coding keys. The keys in the `CodingKeys` enum determines what the synthesised `Codable` implementation will encode and decode. If you don't include `userType`, `userType` will not be encoded, so it will not be stored into `UserDefaults`.

> I am not getting it from Server and userType is an external property outside the JSON response

This is fine, because `userType` is optional. If the JSON does not have the key, it will be assigned `nil`. This might be a problem if you are also encoding `User` and sending it to the server, *and* that the server can't handle extra keys in the request, in which case you need two structs - one for storing to/loading from `UserDefaults`, one for parsing/encoding server response/request.

Remember to encode a new `User` to `UserDefaults` when you try this out, since the old one still doesn't have the `userType` encoded with it.

Answer (score 1):

### Observations

1. Having a custom implementation for `Decodable` part of `enum UserType: Int, Codable` is probably not the best idea. Swift compiler supports encoding/decoding `enum X: Int` out of the box without having you to write custom implementation for it. (In fact, starting with Swift 5.5, Swift compiler can now do this for enums that have cases with associated values as well.)
2. You should **try to avoid** having cases like `.notDetermined`. Either user has a type that's well defined or user.type is `nil`. You can easily define convenience getters on user itself to know about it's type.
3. Swift allows nesting of types, so having `User.Kind` instead of `UserType` is more natural in Swift.

Following implementation takes care of all of these points.

```
import Foundation

class User: Codable {
    enum Kind: Int, Codable {
        case free = 1
        case pro = 2
    }
    public var fullName: String?
    public var kind: Kind?
}

let newUser = User()
newUser.fullName = "Test"
newUser.kind = .free

do {
    let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(newUser)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "appUser")
    
    if let fetched = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "appUser") as? Data {
        let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: fetched)
        print(decoded)
    }
}
```

Above code includes definition, construction, encodeAndStore, fetchAndDecode and it does everything you need without any custom implementation.

---

#### Bonus

Above code does not print a nice description for the `User`. For that, you can add `CustomStringConvertible` conformance like this.

```
extension User: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        """
        fullName: \(fullName ?? "")
        kind: \(kind?.description ?? "")
        """
    }
}

extension User.Kind: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .free: return "free"
        case .pro: return "pro"
        }
    }
}
```

If you try `print(decoded)` after implementing this, you will clearly see what you want to see for `User` instance.

---

###### `User.kind` can be `nil` and I don't want to handle it with `if let` every time I need to check this from different screens in the app.

No worries, it can be simplified to this.

```
extension User {
    var isFreeUser: Bool { kind == .free }
    var isProUser: Bool { kind == .pro }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this great understanding about CustomStringConvertible protocol and how can I nest the enum for my Custom class. Really appreciate it !

Comment: In the answer, you can see `enum Kind` is nested inside `class User`. See how we write `extension User.Kind`

Comment: Yes I reviewed that and modified my current integration in that way only. Thanks for this great help and creating a clear class !